# Get specific roster with name on eJabberd server using strophe.js

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe

Is it possible to get a specific roster that I've created on a xmpp chat server such as [EveryBody](https://www.ejabberd.im/shared-roster-all) ?

I can get all the users of the **EveryBody** roster like this :

```
function getInfo(){
    usersList = [];
    iq = $iq({type: 'get'}).c('query', {xmlns: 'jabber:iq:roster'});
    conn.sendIQ(iq, userList);
}
```

Assuming now that my roster name is : **myRoster** .

Is there a way to specify the name of this roster in a request that we send  to the chat server to get all the members of this roster ?

Answer (score 0):

That's not how shared roster work. When properly configured, shared roster are retrieve automatically inside the user standard roster. When requiring the roster, the shared rosters for that user are merged with the standard user roster.

So, if you create a shared roster from ejabberd web admin like example 1: every body see everybody else from that domain.

Here is the setup for that roster:

```
Name: EveryBody
Description: This group contains everybody
Members: @all@
Displayed Groups: everybody
```

Please, make sure shared_roster module is also enabled in ejabberd configuration file.

When you login on ejabberd, simply send a roster get to the server and you will get the populated roster.